# Facing difficulty with my boss attitude

Tags: software-industry, management, work-environment

I joined in a new company almost 45 days ago, my boss is workaholic and not even considering anything. He don't notice if the tasks not finish in time if I work more time in a day. I am completing my tasks regularly and coming and leaving on time. I faced one difficult situation yesterday one of my friend in Hospital he needs o-ve (rare blood group) blood immediately, so I called to my HR to explain the situation and I sent to message to my boss. I spent almost a day in hospital. But my boss is not understanding and asking me seriously why not intimated again in afternoon and in evening. I got huge frustration at that time and am fully fedup with him. He even not understanding the situation treating me like a machine. I am thinking to quit this job but I not even worked at least 6 months here. But I can't work with the people who doesn't care a life of human.Is my decision right if I quit the job for this reason

Comment: I'm not sure there is a question in here, or at least one we can answer I'm afraid.  You can either try to work with your boss and improve the situation, or you go elsewhere.  We can't tell you which you should do.

Comment: Can't you take your laptop and work remotely?

Comment: Yeah, I'd not want to work for a boss who prioritizes work over possibly saving someone's life, when you had already even notified him what was going on.  But, better to line up another job first, and tell prospective companies "it turned out to not be a good fit."

Answer (score 4):

You're already helped your friend. You've won - your boss did not fire you. And if your friend needs help again, you'd help yourfriend regardless of what the boss says or thinks.

Again, you've won - You helped your friend. If you quit your job at this point in time without lining up another job, you've just fired yourself. Not sure what message you hope to be sending your boss by dumping yourself on the pavement without having another job lined up. Line up another job first before you quit. If your boss wants to fire you before you've got another job lined up, make the boss work at firing you.

If a prospective employer asks you why you are changing job, cite irreconciliable personal differences and leave it at that.